# Magento override addAction method(CartController.php)

Tags: php, magento, controller, overriding

What I want is to override the addAction method.

What I have so far is:

config.xml(in MyModule/CartOverride/etc/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
<MyModule_CartOverride>
<version>0.1.0</version>
</MyModule_CartOverride>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
     <checkout>
         <args>
           <modules>
             <MyModule_CartOverride before="Mage_Checkout">MyModule_CartOverride</MyModule_CartOverride>
           </modules>
         </args>
     </checkout>
   </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

MyModule_Override.xml(in app/etc/modules/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_CartOverride>
            <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </MyModule_CartOverride>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And CartController(in MyModule/Override/controllers/CartController.php)

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class MyModule_CartOverride_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'addAction is modified';
        die();
        // parent::addAction();
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'indexAction is modified';
        // parent::indexAction();
    }
}
?>
```

Overriding indexAction is succesful but not addAction(it keeps it's default behaviour).
Magento version is 1.9.1.

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve?  I'd recommend instead using the Magento Events system to detect a new item added to the cart, then adding the functionality to your event function.  This is a lot safer and more efficient way then rewriting the core controllers.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make adding to cart possible with AJAX. I'm following this tutorial: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/ but it's for the whole shop. My idea is to override the addAction method and use the overriden controller only in my mobile theme and the core one on the desktop theme.

Comment: Controllers are not theme specific, writing logic to detect a theme and change the controller doesn't make sense.  You should bind the ajax functionality to a button and only include that in your desktop theme using the theme files (phtml), not your core files (controllers, models etc)

Comment: If you're not familiar with properly customizing Magento, I'd recommend using a 3rd party extension to implement Ajax, it will save you a lot of time.  Here's a free one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxcart-3-15606.html

Comment: I'm not planning to write logic in the controller to detect if the device/theme is mobile or not. I'm just following that tutorial. You can ignore the mobile thing. I just want to be able to override the addAction method.